# I am trying to parse 350 files on my local disk and store the data into database as json objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json, python-3.x

I am parsing 350 txt files having json data using python. I am able to retrieve 62 of those object and store them on mysql database, but after that I am getting an error saying `JSONDecodeError: ExtraData`

Python:

```
import os
import ast
import json
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='137800000', database='shaproject',client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES])
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

sql3 = """INSERT INTO shaproject.alttwo (alttwo_id,responses) VALUES """

os.chdir('F:/Code Blocks/SEM 2/DM/Project/350/For Merge Disqus')
current_list_dir=os.listdir()
print(current_list_dir)
cur_cwd=os.getcwd()
cur_cwd=cur_cwd.replace('\\','/')
twoid=1

for every_file in current_list_dir:
    file=open(cur_cwd + "/" + every_file)
    utffile=file.read()
    data=json.loads(utffile)
    for i in range(0,len(data['response'])):
        data123 = json.dumps(data['response'][i])
        tup=(twoid,data123)
        print(sql3+str(tup))
        twoid+=1
        cursor.execute(sql3+str(tup)+";")
        print(tup)
    mariadb_connection.commit()
```

I have searched online and found that multiple dump statements are resulting in this error. But I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with a database nor with the number of files. Please check  `json.loads` on the 63th file (i.e. where your code it fails) and it will likely fail there without any database or other files involved. My guess is that this file simply contains these extra data it complains about, which means you need to fix this file and not your code.

Comment: yes....I just check that..it is accessing the same file 62 times but not the next file... @SteffenUllrich Can you please check and find why only one file is being accessed...I am unable to figure it out..

Comment: Only the first file is being accessed even though I am passing the rest of the names and setting them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

Rather than `os.listdir()`, which is too permissive,
use glob to focus on just the `*.json` files.

Print out the name of the file before asking `.loads()` to parse it.
Rename any badly formatted files to `.txt` rather than `.json`, in order to skip them.

Note that you can pass the open file directly to [`.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), if you wish.

Closing open files would be a good thing.
Rather than a direct assignment (with no `close()`!)
you would be better off with [`with`](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open(cur_cwd + "/" + every_file) as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Talking about current current working directory seems
both repetitive and redundant.
It would suffice to call it `cwd`.